# What is the interpretation of composition of density matrices?

Tags: density-operator

Like all operators on a Hilbert space, you can tensor together density matrices, so $\eta = \rho \otimes \rho$ always exists.  What about composition i.e. just multiplying them, so $\xi = \rho \cdot \rho$?  What does matrix multiplication mean for density matrices?

Answer (score 2):

There is no special meaning for a product of that kind. Surely, it is not a density matrix in general (take $\frac12I$, where $I$ is the 2-by-2 identity matrix), contrary to the tensor product.

Note, however, that for every density matrix $\rho$ there always is a matrix $b$ such that $\rho = b^2$.